# ionic4 doesn't support android 5

Tags: ionic4

When the android platform is added, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview will be added by default.
Packaging and installing on mobile phones is black screen，
because this plugin does not support android 5.
Uninstall the plugin, go to install, white screen.
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview required for ionic4 ?

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem is that Android 5 and lower don't support ES6:

You can find more details, and several options here:

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15438

If you really need to support Android5, perhaps your best bet might be to use [Crosswalk](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview):

https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova.html

You can see the relative usage for different Android versions on Google's [Distribution Dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/):

[image]